# how to create curl file in php to fetch data from url?

Tags: php

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

return $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. You have to set an URL to get something.
I hope I understood your question

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.example.com",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```